# Borland C++ 5.02 cannot call constructor with parameters

Tags: c++, constructor, unresolved-external, borland-c++

I Have the following class definition in a header file I copied from the net

```
#ifndef A2DD_H
#define A2DD_H

class A2DD
{
    int gx;
    int gy;
public:
    A2DD();
    A2DD(int x,int y);
};
#endif
```

And in the implementation file i have
`

```
#include "A2DD.h" 

A2DD::A2DD()
{
}

A2DD::A2DD(int x,int y)
{
  gx = x;
  gy = y;
}
```

Now the problem is that i get the following error when the constructor with parameters are called.

Info :Building...

Info :Compiling C:\Users...\Desktop\main.cpp

Info :Linking C:\Users...\Desktop\main.exe

Error:  Error: Unresolved external 'A2DD::A2DD(int,int)' referenced from C:\USERS...\DESKTOP\MAIN.OBJ

```
#include "A2DD.h"
int main()
  {
     A2DD add(2,3);
     return 0;
  }
```

However when `A2DD add();` is called without parameters the program works fine.

Now you might be wondering why I copied code from the internet, well I have a programming assignment for some electrical engineering course that involves classes and we can only use Borland and yes the code worked in visual c++...helpp please

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile and link the file where you implement the constructors (`A2DD.cpp`). You need to tell Borland that this is an implementation file that belongs to your project.

What you misunderstood is this:

```
A2DD add();
```

It does **not** call the default constructor, it only declares a function called `add` which returns a `A2DD` and has no parameters. This function declaration therefore basically does nothing in your code and the default constructor is never called.

If you want to create an object with the default constructor, you need

```
A2DD add;
```

Comment: I added a `int main()` to the A2DD.cpp file and it worked however i want to use these classes in a separate .cpp file. How would you go about it that way

Comment: @SaKabmar_Ashna I am not using Borland so I can't answer that, sorry.

Comment: thanks for your response but that still doesnt solve my problem

Comment: @SaKabmar_Ashna There should be a way to add `A2DD.cpp` to the current active project in the ide. Failing that you can always compile this from the command line. eg. `bcc32 -tWC -v a2dd.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: I solved the problem i will post the solution 2morrow online when i have time...will definitely share my experience thanks all